# Setting an iid for a treeview in tkinter python -Error

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

As the title suggests i have these lines of code :

```
tree=ttk.Treeview(acc_tab)
tree.place(x=0,y=0,width=400,height=250)
tree["columns"]=("one")

tree.column("#0",width=270, minwidth=270, stretch=NO)
tree.column("one",width=270, minwidth=270, stretch=NO)

tree.heading("#0",text="Account",anchor=W)
tree.heading("one",text="Amount",anchor=W)

savings_folder=tree.insert('',4,iid="D",text="Savings",values=("$"+str(db_acc.get_savings_amount()),))
tree.insert(savings_folder,1,iid="saF0",text=db_acc.view_acc()[i][1],values=("$"+str(db_acc.view_acc()[i][3]),))
```

as a result of running this code i get the following eror :

```
File "front_end_exp_det.py", line 165, in <module>
    tree.insert(savings_folder,1,iid="saF0",text=db_acc.view_acc()[i][1],values=("$"+str(db_acc.view_acc()[i][3]),))
  File "C:\Users\Eliran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 1368, in insert
    "-id", iid, *opts)
_tkinter.TclError: Item saF0 already exists
```

The error suggests that the iid i chose is already taken as i understand it - so i tried to modify it countless times - but the error still persists.

Side note : if i take out the iid argument from the insert function the code is running with no errors.

Comment: Hmm I don’t have an error. Are you using the same id in a loop?

Comment: ***"take out the iid argument ... with no errors"***: Then it gets auto generated: [ttk.Treeview.insert](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview.insert).

Comment: YES ! 
I called insert inside a loop . changed the iid argument to be dependent of the loop index. 
It is working now , thank you.